# Error opening sqlite table using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
   RUN    YR  AP15  PMTE     RSPC  NPPC      NEE     SSF      PRK  QDRN 
0    1  2008  4.53  0.04   641.21  16.8   624.41  328.66  2114.51     0 
1    1  2009  3.17  0.03  1428.30   0.0  1428.30   23.58     3.20     0 
2    1  2010  6.20  0.03  1124.97   0.0  1124.97   23.94    18.45     0 
3    1  2011  5.38  0.02   857.76   0.0   857.76   28.40    42.54     0 
4    1  2012  7.32  0.02   831.42   0.0   831.42   23.92    25.58     0
```

I am storing the above dataframe in a sqlite db as follows:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
db_name = 'sqlite:///C:\\tmp.db'
engine  = create_engine(db_name)
df.to_sql(db_name, engine, if_exists='append')
```

However, I get an error when I try to read it back:

```
df = pandas.read_sql_table(db_name, 'sqlite:///C:\\tmp.db')

ValueError: Table sqlite:///C:tmp.db not found
```

The tmp.db is created, since I can see it in SQLite studio. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does 'sqlite:///C:/tmp.db' work?

Comment: unfortunately, it does not

Comment: The syntax for specifying the sqlalchemy URL is explained [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/engines.html#sqlite), so you url seems fine. Are you sure that file exists?

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using? Specifying a string URL instead of an engine object is only added in the recently released 0.17.0

Comment: Ahh, I am using pandas 0.16.*, if you can put your comment as answer, I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying a string URL instead of an engine object is only added in the recently released 0.17.0. So you need to first construct the engine object:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///C:\\tmp.db')
df = pandas.read_sql_table(db_name, engine)
```